# How do you get your tax transcript if you are a citizen of another country?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, jamaica

My parent is not a citizen of the United States and my school is requiring that they get a tax transcript from their country. Is my parent going to have to go to that country to get the physical paper?

Comment: What school, for what purpose, and what country? Generally, this is something you'd call the consulate to get assistance with.

Comment: A college in NJ for verification process and Jamaica

Comment: Before asking the consulate, call the school's financial aid office and ask them for assistance. They deal with this sort of thing on a very regular basis and can probably tell you exactly what to do ... and they will know exactly what kind of documents that particular school needs.